# Assignment (str=$*) trying to run as a command in bash

Tags: shell, palindrome

input in terminal:

```
cd Desktop
chmod 777 isPalindromeFun.sh
./isPalindromeFun.sh
isPalindrome madam
```

gives an error: `str=madam not found`

```
#!/bin/bash

function isPalindrome () {
if [ "$#" -ne 0 ];
then
inc=$1; # if it has arguments set the increment with the first argument
fi

[ $# -eq 0 ] && { read str ;} || \ str=$*

String="$(echo $str | sed 's/[^[:alnum:]]//g' | \
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')"

if [ "$(echo $String | rev)" = "$String" ]
then
echo "\"$str\" is a palindrome"
else
echo "\"$str\" is not a palindrome"
fi
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The backslash needs to be removed when writing this as a single line:

```
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] && { read str ;} || \ str=$*
```

It would make more sense if writing the code as two lines:

```
[ "$#" -eq 0 ] && { read str ;} || \
  str=$*
```

On just one line, however, the backslash only has the effect of escaping the character following it -- making that next character, a space, be data rather than syntax -- and thus makes your command

```
str=$*
```

instead be the same as

```
" str="$*
```

meaning the space is *part of the command*. That's not a valid assignment, and of course there's no command called `" str=madam"` (starting with a space!) on your system.

---

Aside: `$#` doesn't strictly need to be quoted -- unless you have `IFS` set to a value that contains numbers, the results from expanding `$#` are guaranteed to expand to a single word -- but I'm doing so here as a workaround for StackOverflow's syntax highlighting.

Comment: Does that `\` have any purpose when continuing after `||`? Isn't that already a legal continuation point?

Comment: @EtanReisner, you're quite right -- that's why I said "would make more sense", as opposed to saying that it would be _necessary_ in that case. It would at least be communicating authorial intent.